# Android Jetpack Navigations: navigate from "non-navigation" fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using Jetpack Navigation in my app, I've now came across a situation I don't fully understand.
I have a fragment `CouponFragment` which is supposed to be used in multiple places (inside other fragments via static xml tag and inside a bottomSHeetDialog not connected to navGraph). I need this fragment to be able to navigate to a `WebviewFragment` which is a destination in the navGraph.
I added the navigation entry for `CouponFragment`:

In the most simple case (`CouponFragment` inside another navigation-connected fragment) the solution is pretty straight-forward, I added an action to the fragment which contains `CouponFragment`, for example:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_results"
        android:name="ResultsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_results">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_webview"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_webview" />
    </fragment>
```

This works. The real problem comes when I try to navigate from `CouponFragment` which is inside a `BottomSheetFragmentDialog`. I tried adding an action to the navigation-connected fragment which invokes the dialog:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:name="ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_webview"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_webview" />
    </fragment>
```

but that results in this exeception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination package.name:id/action_webview cannot be found from the current destination Destination(package.name:id/navigation_webview) class=WebViewFragment
```

which is strange becuase looks like is searching the action on the destination fragment. I tried adding a `action_webview` to `navigation_webview`:

just to see what would happen and nothing does. No logs are printed.

Could anyone give a hint on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start to unswer to the main question only because the details is very ambiguous and edit if necessary.

To navigate from a non_navigation fragment:

1. Use a deep link, here is the doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link
2. Just use the ParentFragmentDirections and the current NavController.

So for example:

- FragmentA with nested Non-Navigation-FragmentY
- FragmentB

to navigate from FragmentY to FragmentB just load the NavController from the MainNavigationHostFragment and set as destination "FragmentADirections.actionFragmentA_to_FragmentB()"

Comment: that makes sense. I'll try it and accept if of any help. Could you point out what do you find ambiguous in the question so I can improve it?

Comment: Well it is not clear how many nav graphs and host fragments you have; the way this nn navigation fragment is nested or if the wrapper bottom sheet dialog fragment is a dialog destination inside the nav graph. You could actually avoid to use specifiic names and just propose the navigation scheme you are trying to achieve